Vue v-model detect parent ref change
I am trying to create two-way binding but the problem is that I need to know what exactly changes the model ref: parent or child component.
When using watch it simply catches all changes and I can't find the way to distinguish the source of change.
<script setup>
// Parent.vue

const doc = ref('');

setTimeout(() => {
    // Update this ref AND trigger watch in Child.vue
    doc.value = 'new value from parent';
}, 2000);
</script>

<template>
    <Child v-model:doc="doc" />
</template>

<script setup>
// Child.vue

const doc = defineModel('doc');

setTimeout(() => {
    // DO NOT TRIGGER WATCH ON THIS ONE!
    // But still update parent `doc` ref
    doc.value = 'new inner value';
}, 3000);

watch(doc, newValue => {
    // Catch `new value from parent` but not `new inner value`
});
</script>


It's unclear why you need it to work this way and not another. Consider explaining your actual case, a possible solution may depend on it. You may need both child and parent state

@EstusFlask I am working with CodeMirror and its requires some special functional way of working with it. Basically, if doc is changed from parent I want to call dispatch(newDoc) method which replaces the content of editor, but when user changes the code inside the editor it calls docChanged event with newDoc return value. If I update doc ref from docChanged event it triggers my watch for parent change detection which than triggers dispatch(newDoc) reinserting the same content inside editor and ruining cursor position.

Can you provide a workable demo like stackblitz? I don't see how this correlates with the example with setTimeout. As said, this is specific to the implementation. I'd go with parent+child state so you can easily track where a change comes from in a watcher and conditionally synchronize them

@EstusFlask ok I will provide a demo within an hour or two. Need to go right now)

Sure, let me know if there's an update. This approach suggested in the answer may work but it is a quick fix that may have downsides depending on the case

@EstusFlask Ready. Try to put cursor somewhere in the middle of editor and input somthing. You will see cursor jumps to start because all editor content gets replaced: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-tezj8i?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCodeMirror.vue

Thanks, can you clarify on which condition " doc is changed from parent"? Does this just happen asynchronously at some point?

@EstusFlask by "changed from parent" I mean that you can change doc outside from CodeMirror component to insert completely new document inside editor) This is useful when you don't let the user to change the code and instead load this code from somewhere else. That is why I want to implement two-way binding model: you can change the code inside editor and outside.

I see. I posted what it can look like, this is how I handled this in similar cases.

To me, this seems like a case to not use defineModel (which is just a convenience), instead to explicitly control-and-watch all flows. If you end up creating an arbitrary flag, then you're just introducing complexity. Why not go the official way?

Use a flag in the child:
See on Vue SFC Playground
<script setup>
import {watch} from 'vue';
const doc = defineModel('doc');
let meChangingDoc = false;

setTimeout(() => {
    // DO NOT TRIGGER WATCH ON THIS ONE!
    // But still update parent `doc` ref
    meChangingDoc = true;
    doc.value = 'new inner value';
}, 3000);

watch(doc, newValue => {
  if(meChangingDoc) {
    meChangingDoc = false; 
    console.log('child changed doc');
    return;
  }
  console.log('parent changed doc')
  
    // Catch `new value from parent` but not `new inner value`
});
</script>

You can use a generic function also:
See on Vue SFC Playground
SyncRef.js
import {watch} from 'vue';
export default function syncRef(source){
  let syncing = false;
  return new Proxy(source, {
    get(_, prop){
      if(prop === 'watchSource') return function(cb){
        return watch(source, (...args) => {
          if(syncing) {syncing = false; return; }
          cb(...args);
        });
      };
      return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }, 
    set(_, prop, val){
      if(prop === 'value'){
        syncing = true;
        source.value = val;
        return true;
      }
      return Reflect.set(...arguments);
    }
  });
}

Usage:
<script setup>
import syncRef from './SyncRef';
const model = defineModel('doc');
const doc = syncRef(model);

doc.watchSource(newValue => {
    // Catch `new value from parent` but not `new inner value`
});
</script>


Thank you. I tried to use flag but it did not hit me that I can = false it right in watch and not trying to create some wrappers such as withInternalChange(() => { ... }).

@CMTV added also a generic function that you could reuse in many places

v-model makes it easy to lift up the state to parent component and provide two-way binding, and there is no reason to introduce local state unless there's a need for it, such as the need to distinguish between updates to child and parent state. Since this is the case here, it can be solved with a watcher that takes multiple changes into account (a demo):
  // Child.vue
const parentState = defineModel();
const childState = ref();

watch(
  [parentState, childState],
  ([newParentState, newChildState], [oldParentState, oldChildState]) => {
    const isInitial = newChildState == undefined;
    const isParent = 
      newChildState === oldChildState &&
      (newParentState !== newChildState);

    if (isParent || isInitial) {
      childState.value = newParentState;
      // parent-only update logic
    } else {
      parentState.value = newChildState;
      // child-only update logic
    }
  },
  { immediate: true }
);

Since such watchers are prone to recursive changes, additional conditions can be added to avoid them if necessary.

you should introduce the flag to track the source of the change
<template>
  <Child v-model:doc="doc" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const doc = ref('');

setTimeout(() => {
  doc.value = 'new value from parent';
}, 2000);
</script>

and here is the child.vue
<script setup>
import { defineModel, watch, ref } from 'vue';

const doc = defineModel('doc');
const changeSource = ref('');

watch(doc, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  if (newValue !== oldValue && changeSource.value === 'parent') {
    console.log('Change from parent:', newValue);
  } else if (newValue !== oldValue && changeSource.value === 'child') {
    console.log('Change from child:', newValue);
  }
});
</script>

